# How to create sockets in C++ with Winsock2?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, sdk

I'm trying to create sockets with a video a found on youtube. 
Here's the video: [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBAAbp6cNpg)
I tried the code, just like the video, but it keeps giving me errors and I can't compile it.

> sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory.

I'm using Dev, and also tried to put the sdkddkver.h code in the same directory, nothing happened. Downloaded the Windows SDK but still.

Here's my final code after the video:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib");

#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    long answer;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2,1); 
    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &wsaData);

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);



    SOCKET = sListen; 
    SOCKET = sConnect; 



    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);



    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet.ad_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);


    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind (sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);
    for (;;){
        cout << "Awaiting incoming conection..." << endl;
        if (sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
            {
                cout << "Connection Found"<< endl;
            }
    }
    cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: A few suggestions regarding style/correctness: 1) Since you're using `iostream` for your console I/O, the `stdio.h` and `conio.h` headers are redundant. 2) `DLLVERSION` does not get initialized and `DLLVERSION - MAKEWORD(2,1);` does nothing. 3) You should close your sockets before your application exits.

Comment: Did you try simply not including sdkddkver.h? Also I'd suggest you just look for a better example using sockets: this one starts with including 3 files, none of which are required for using sockets at all. Not good.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you need `sdkddkver.h`.